Inno Setup - Change next Page
Is there a way to define which page should come next in Inno Setup?
I have a custom page in which the user is offered 4 options, depending on the selection, a different page should then appear.
Unfortunately I haven't found a real way to implement this yet.
I have looked at the code examples from Inno Setup and the structure of the base class of WizardForm.

The codedlg.iss example shows you how to do this. Specifically, see the code for ShouldSkipPage and NextButtonClick.

Custom page is shown after the page specified as parameter in CreateCustomPage() function, for example in this case after wpWelcome page:
CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Installation type', '');

Use this to shown your custom page and combination of ShouldSkipPage() calls to show/hide appropriate pages.

Thank you very much for the answer, that helped me :)
